# Comment are not getting updated + asp .net mvc + repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, repository-pattern

I am trying to build a blog application using asp .net mvc. The blog was working fine but I have not tired to introduce repository pattern. I started with the code below which works - i.e. I can add blogs, comments and edit/delete them. However, I changed the code a little and everything fell over. I do not understand what is wrong.

I started with this code, which works:

IBlogRepository:

```
public interface IBlogRepository
{
    IQueryable<Blog> FindAllBlogs();
    Blog GetBlog(int id);
    void Add(Blog blog);
    void Update(Blog blog);
    void Delete(Blog blog);

    void Add(Comment comment);
    //void Remove(Comment comment);
}
```

BlogRepository:

```
public class BlogRepository : IBlogRepository
    {
     ....
     public void Add(Blog blog)
        {
            db.Blogs.Add(blog);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
     ....
}
```

Blog Controller:

```
    IBlogRepository blogrepository;

    public BlogController()
    {
        blogrepository = new BlogRepository();
    }

     .....
    public ActionResult Create(Blog blog)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            blog.Content = Regex.Replace(blog.Content, " {2,}", x => x.Value.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
            blog.Content = blog.Content.Replace("\n", "<br/>");
            blogrepository.Add(blog);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(blog);
    }
    .....
   }
```

The change and the code that doesn't work is:

IBlogRepository:

```
public interface IBlogRepository
{
    IQueryable<Blog> FindAllBlogs();
    Blog GetBlog(int id);
    T Update<T>(T entity) where T : class;
    T Add<T>(T entity) where T : class;
    T Delete<T>(T entity) where T : class;
}
```

BlogRepository:

```
public class BlogRepository : BlogDb, IBlogRepository {
...
        T INPLHBlogRepository.Add<T>(T entity)
        {
            return Set<T>().Add(entity);
        }
...
}
```

What did I break? Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So you have switched to an explicit interface implementation of the add method. It looks like you have a typo.

With explicit implementation.

```
public class BlogRepository : BlogDb, IBlogRepository {
...
        T IBlogRepository.Add<T>(T entity)
        {
            return Set<T>().Add(entity);
        }
...
}
```

And without

```
public class BlogRepository : BlogDb, IBlogRepository {
...
        public T Add<T>(T entity)
        {
            return Set<T>().Add(entity);
        }
...
}
```